# How to detect long press on object using Unity EnhancedTouch?

Tags: unity, touch

I want to implement a feature in my mobile game where if you press on a game object for a certain amount of time while not moving your finger an animation will play. I also need to be able to drag and drop objects. I have the drag and drop functionality working already, but know I also need the press and hold feature. I have this code at the moment:

```
 private void Update()
 {
    foreach (var touch in Touch.activeTouches)
    {
        // Only respond to first finger
        if (touch.finger.index == 0 && touch.isInProgress)
        {
            Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.screenPosition);

            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(ray);

            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
                print("Selected: " + hit.collider.name);
                // Drag game object
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This code works just like I want it. You put a finger on the screen and a ray is used to select an object that I can drag. But I am not sure where to start on the other feature described in the paragraph above, there is a [startTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch.Touch.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_EnhancedTouch_Touch_startTime) and a [startScreenPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch.Touch.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_EnhancedTouch_Touch_startScreenPosition) property that maybe can be used for this, but I don't know how. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of notes: Unless you specifically want to check that the user keeps their finger on the desired object at all times, I would probably only check at the beginning of the touch, as well as the moment when you want the *hold* to trigger.

You can simply compare the `startTime` property to `Time.realTimeSinceStartup` and check when a certain amount of time has passed. You then just need to take care of only calling a method or performing some action **once!**

````csharp
private const float HoldTime = 0.5f;
private bool _triggeredHold = false;

private void Update()
{   
    foreach (var touch in Touch.activeTouches)
    {
        if (touch.finger.index == 0 && touch.began)
        {
            _triggeredHold = false;
        }

        // Only respond to first finger
        if (touch.finger.index == 0 && touch.isInProgress)
        {
            var delta = Time.realTimeSinceStartup - touch.startTime;  

            if (delta > HoldTime && _triggeredHold == false)
            {
                _triggeredHold = true;
                
                // Do something
            }

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```
````